# Developing speedometer in Android?

Tags: android, performance

I want to develop speedometer in Android which will display the speed of the user. For that I have one image which has speed readings like 5, 10, 15 and so on. Now, I want to move the arrow on that. If the speed is 5 then that arrow should move from 0 to 5. Can someone help me out as how that can be done?

Comment: Quite a loose question -- how far have you got so far? Do you have any code? Are you using speed calculated from GPS?

Comment: Obviously I will be using speed from GPS. I want to know how can I move the arrow to particular position.

Comment: I have been able to rotate the arrow image with RotationAnimation and TranslateAnimation. What happens is that when there is an update for speed then the new animation should start from the previous speed but it starts from the position which has been set in layout file. Suppose I had speed of 5 initially so it animates from the initial position in xml to 5 and then when the speed goes to 20 then it should animate from 5 to 20 but it goes back to the position specifiec in xml. Can someone help me out in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem with the help of http://mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer/comment-page-1/#comment-14326

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with an arrow image with a transparent background, and draw it over the dial image, rotating it to match the right speed.

Comment: I have transparent arrow image and the thing that I am looking for is rotating that arrow image over dial image. Do you know how that can be done? Do I need to use translation animation or something else?

Comment: I'd blank the canvas, directly calculate the right angle, and just redraw the two images onto the canvas to create the next frame. There are samples in the android sdk that deal with the rendering aspects.

Comment: I have been able to rotate the arrow image with RotationAnimation and TranslateAnimation. What happens is that when there is an update for speed then the new animation should start from the previous speed but it starts from the position which has been set in layout file. Suppose I had speed of 5 initially so it animates from the initial position in xml to 5 and then when the speed goes to 20 then it should animate from 5 to 20 but it goes back to the position specifiec in xml. Can someone help me out in this?

Comment: Can you please explain a bit what do you mean to say by calculating right angle and redrawing the two images?

Answer (score 0):

I think this code gives you the movement of needle .Try to  make some changes in the code so that the arrow can move frm 0-5.

Use this link ......May be it will give the result

http://mobisoftinfotech.com/custom-speedometer/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.